# Jenkins maven job error: AntClassLoader

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant

I face an issue where it is impossible to run a maven project on Jenkins. I want to run it on the OS X slave where I have installed JDK, Maven and Ant. When I run the job it gives me instantly this error:

```
Building remotely on Mini-node (ios-mini) in workspace /Users/mini-node/Jenkins/workspace/soapui-smp-tests
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Mini-node failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:786)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:629)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildClassRealm(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:94)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.getMavenVersion(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:188)
    at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:70)
    at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:42)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to Mini-node(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1413)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:778)
    ... 7 more
Finished: FAILURE
```